# Header (h1) takes up a lot space to the right

Tags: html, css

[image: chrome debug]

For some reason, as can be seen in the screenshot, the h1 (discordbotgen) takes up a lot of space to the right, whilst not specified in my css. I don't want it taking that space, as it blocks other elements from going there.

```
.main-title {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #ededed;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 180px;
}
```

```
<h1 class="main-title">discordbotgen</h1>
```

The h1 doesn't have any parent divs, it's parent is `<body>`.

Comment: you need to read about block element and inline element

Comment: Headers will always take up the whole width of their container. I would suggest wrapping it in a `div` and handle position using that div

Comment: thank you for asking this I couldn't quite articulate what the problem was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<h1>` is display-block by default - It will take up the whole width of its containing element. You can float it or use `inline-block` to change that functionality.

p.s. If you use floats dont forget to use clearfix. [Clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements

By default `<h1>` is a block level element. It will take up the full width of it's container unless you specify it to be `inline-block`.

```css
h1 {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<h1>Block Element</h1>
```

```css
h1 {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Block Element</h1>
```